# Django ORM Group BY and return additional fields

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to perform query like this:

```
SELECT loan_id, tenor, amount COUNT(id) AS total FROM loan GROUP BY loan_id
```

But, I want only use 1 group by field "loan_id", how to return other fields like "tenor", "amount"

I don't want tenor and amount in GROUP BY clause.

How to achive using django ORM?

This is result without group by:

loan_id |   tenor | amount

36573   11  900000.00

36573   11  900000.00

36571   2   1800000.00

36571   11  1800000.00

**I want to result like this:**

loan_id | tenor |   amount |    total

36571   2   1800000.00  2

36573   11  900000.00   2

Comment: Well that does not make any sense. Either `tenor` is *functional dependent* on `loan_id`, and then putting it in the `GROUP BY` makes *no* difference, or if it is not, then it is possible that for the *same* `loan_id`, there are two or more `tenor`s, then which one should be returned? What if it contains `tenor1`, `tenor2`, and `tenor3`? Should we return the smallest (lexicographically)? Or the largest? This is why if you perform a `GROUP BY`, the remaining fields either should be functional dependent, or should be aggregates. In SQL this should normally fail as well.

Comment: can you show correct `sql` before try to release it in django orm.

Comment: If you run this in an SQL console, you will get an error like "contains a non-aggregate column which is not functional dependent on `loan_id`".

Comment: @BearBrown I edited on my question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, it's not showing an error

Comment: Looks like you disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` then, looks like a huge anti-pattern :( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hmm, it's default from mysql installation. Im not changing configuration. I'm using MariaDB server version 10.1.28.

Comment: @andrey_derma: well I tested this on a fresh installation (Virtual machine) and it definitely shows an error. This is also logical. In case you want to return a `tenor`, it makes sense to simply specify which one, for example `MIN(tenor)`, such that in case there are multiple, it is clear which one is returned.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem aah..! got it. using MIN and other aggregation function. thanks!